# Does extern "C" have any effect in C?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

I just got some C code that uses extern "C" to declare external functions like this:

```
extern "C" void func();
```

Is this valid C?  I'm getting an error at this line,  but I'm not sure if it's because of this or something else.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, it's not valid C.  It should only be used in C++ code to refer to functions defined in C code.  The `extern "C"` should be surrounded in a `ifdef __cplusplus`/`#endif` block:

```
// For one function
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void func();

// For more than one function
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void func1();
void func2();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 13):

this is a C++ notation to tell the compiler/linker to use C calling standards.

Usually that line is wrapped in an pre-processor statement.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// stuff

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Not valid in C. If present after preprocessing this will result in a diagnostic as per the standard.

For C++, this turns of name-mangling. See [this](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#callC) for more details as to why it may be required. Can you post some more details?