# When to use extern "C" in C++?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we need extern “C”{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)

I have often seen programs coded like:

```
extern "C" bool doSomeWork() {
  //
  return true;
}
```

Why do we use an `extern "C"` block? Can we replace this with something in C++? Is there any advantage to using `extern "C"`?

I do see a link explaining [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1143/) but why do we need to compile something in C when we already have C++?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/extern-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717729/does-extern-c-have-any-effect-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keword-in-c/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

extern "C" makes names not mangled.

It used when:

1. We need to use some C library in C++

   ```
   extern "C" int foo(int);
   ```
2. We need export some C++ code to C

   ```
   extern "C" int foo(int) { something; }
   ```
3. We need an ability to resolve symbol in shared library -- so we need to get rid mangling

   ```
   extern "C" int foo(int) { something; }
   ///
   typedef int (*foo_type)(int);
   foo_type f = (foo_type)dlsym(handle,"foo")
   ```

Answer (score 17):

One place where extern "C" makes sense is when you're linking to a library that was compiled as C code.

```
extern "C" {
  #include "c_only_header.h"
}
```

Otherwise, you might get linker errors because the library contains the functions with C-linkage (_myfunc) but the C++ compiler, which processed the library's header as C++ code, generated C++ symbol names for the functions ("_myfunc@XAZZYE" - this is called mangling and different for each compiler).

Another place where extern "C" is used is to guarantee C linkage even for functions written in C++, eg.

```
extern "C" void __stdcall PrintHello() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Such a function can be exported to a DLL and will then be callable from other programming language because the compile will not mangle its name. If you added another overload of the same function, eg.

```
extern "C" void __stdcall PrintHello() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
extern "C" void __stdcall PrintHello(const char *name) {
  cout << "Hello, " << name << endl;
}
```

Most compilers would then catch this and thus prevent you from using function overloads in your DLL-public functions.