# Getting Undefined symbols for architecture i386 during XCode Single View Compilation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static Library X which is in C. I have another static library Y which is in objective C and its .mm files refer to function of Library X. Now in a single view application I have used Library Y.
But during Compilation its giving an error saying

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "encode()", referenced from:
      _playMediaInternal in libXMedia.a(XMediaInternal.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The above encode function is present in library X which is being used by Library Y and this is used by Single view application. Any suggestions ? I have seen other queries along the same line but had no luck with those. Another thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386)

From the Apple developer site i have been trying to use static libraries [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/iOSStaticLibraries.pdf).

I have connected my phone to the Laptoop and have started compiling against it. its still giving me error. now i feel it has something to do with linking itself rather than architecture

Comment: Me too encountered similar error in case of .o files, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157632/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-in-xcode) ...may help..

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help me

Comment: Have you linked the static library in target Release?

Comment: I have linked X to Y. and then Y to to the application. I still get the error. The error is not able to find symbol from X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the Answer from the stackoverflow link [The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334650/linker-error-calling-c-function-from-objective-c)

I am pasting the exact thing. For me the issue was with the header which was having C Based function call

If you are using c function in c++ file. you should use `extern "c"{}`. 
In .h file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

swrve_currency_given(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);// a c function


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

> extern "C" is meant to be recognized by a C++ compiler and to notify
>   the compiler that the noted function is (or to be) compiled in C
>   style.

If you're linking to a library that was compiled as C code. use

```
extern "C" {
  #include "c_only_header.h"
}
```

Take a look at [When to use extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292138/when-to-use-extern-c-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Your library compiled for ARM architecture, and you try run application in simulator (i386 architecture). Your library must be fat library that supports arm and i386. With `lipo` tool you can make fat library from arm and i386 version. Reed here about it:

http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2010/11/19/making-a-fat-static-library-for-ios-device-and-simulator

Comment: I have connected my phone to the Laptoop and have started compiling against it. its still giving me error. now i feel it has something to do with linking itself rather than architecture