# What are potential disadvantages of using extern "C"?

Tags: c++, extern

I have read

- [When to use extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292138/when-to-use-extern-c-in-c)
- [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)
- [Why do we need extern "C"{ #include <foo.h> } in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c)

However, one question that I have not found an answer to: are there (potentially, future) disadvantages to using `extern "C"` (e.g., on as many functions as possible)?

To be more specific: Is there any disadvantage in adding `extern "C"` to functions whose interface only use C functionality; in other words, those that do not use the features listed in @k-five's answer?

Comment: `extern "C"` is there for serving a purpose . Your question's answer depends on what context you're assuming its pros and cons.

Comment: The disadvantage would be that you cannot use C++ stuff like overloading or member functions. And you have to write more code that doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Despite its name, this is not related to the C language/standard.

Comment: Does it mention how to call C-ABI funtions without it?

Comment: What do you mean with "disadvantage"? If you buy a bike is it a disadvantage you cannot tranport a grande piano with it? That's just not what a bike is for! Don't use a screwdriver to hammer a nail.

Comment: Detecting stack corruption caused by changed declarations at link time is quite superior to having to debug it at runtime.

Comment: @Olaf a disadvantage, to me, is anything that one could do without `extern "C"`, but won't be able to with it. I'm sorry I cannot narrow it down further. I was considering suggesting to someone else to use `extern "C"` by default wherever possible in their C++ code to make it easier for me to use that interface in C.

Comment: @bers: Read my comment **carefully** again. Then think about it!

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks for the advice, I have done that, and my comment above remains the same. Let me explain: a "disadvantage" is "an unfavourable circumstance or condition that reduces the chances of success or effectiveness" ; "reducing" implying a relation to a situation with said circumstance or condition. Now, not being a able to transport a piano with a bike is not a disadvantage in relation to not having a bike, you are right; assuming that I was not able to transport a piano without the bike, either.

Comment: However, my situation is more like having a truck able to transport a piano, and now I downgrade my truck to a bike for financial or environmental reasons. While I myself may be entirely happy with that decision (for example, because I don't have a piano), it is still a disadvantage of a bike in relation to a truck of not being able to transport a piano. Well, it may not be an _effective_ disadvantage now, but it may be in the future; it certainly makes buying a piano more difficult for me. To make you more happy, I have added the work "potential" to the question.

Comment: As a grande piano typically has wheels, it would actually be easier to transport it by foot than bike. [Not that it is really easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3CuXnB928g). But yeah, concentrate on a single part of my comment! Anyway, I don't see how to make you understand the point (apparently other did).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disadvantage is that you can only use features in the interface to `extern "C"` functions that are also available to C functions.

That means:
   1. you can't use default values for function arguments,
   2. you can't use reference arguments,
   3. you can't pass C++ classes by value (including smart pointers),
   4. you can't pass `enum class` arguments,
   5. you can't pass `bool` without converting it to `int`,
   6. you can't overload such functions, and probably more that I can't recall at the moment.

Comment: I don't see that a dsadvantage, because that's what the construct is meant for. (btw: C **has** a boolean type; not useful to convert to `int`).

Comment: @Olaf It is a disadvantage to wrap everything in `extern "C"`, because then you are writing *neither* modern C *nor* modern C++

Comment: This answer is misleading. You **can** use C++ features **inside** `extern "C"` functions. What you **can't** do, is use C++ features in the declaration.. But there's no problem using `std::vector<std::string>` in the implementation. It's unspecified whether C++ `bool` matches C99 `_Boolean`, but his is reasonable to expect.

Comment: That's not a disadvantage, but not what `extern "C"` is meant for. If you want to write C code, use a C compiler, you cannot write C code in a C++ compiler anyway - no matter if wrapped in `extern "C"` or not. The fact you cannot fly with a car is not a disadvantage of a street car, it is just a property. Don't use a screwdriver to hammer a nail.

Comment: @MSalters: It is `_Bool` in C ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl `you can't pass C++ classes by value` does this apply to *all* classes? Even standard layout ones?