# Exporting cpp mangled functions from a 3rd party library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllexport

I have a third party library as source code. It comes with a Visual Studio project that builds a .lib from it.

I want to access the functionality from C# though, so I copied the project and changed it to create a dll.

The DLL didn't contain any exported functions though, so I also created a module definition (.def) file, and added the functions I need in the EXPORTS section.

This works for all the functions that are declared in `extern "C"` blocks. However, some of the functions that I need are declared outside of those blocks.

If I add those to the EXPORTS section I get the error `LNK2001  unresolved external symbol XYZ` :(

I don't want to change the sourcecode of the 3rd party library if I can avoid it.

What's the most elegant and hopefully simplest way to access those functions as well?

**Edit**

One more point for clarification: As far I can tell there is no C++ functionality involved in the interface I want to expose. I honestly don't understand why the 3rd party authors did not just include the few remaining functions into the `extern "C"` blocks. These functions are at the bottom of the header file, maybe the person that added them just made a mistake and put them outside of the `extern "C"` blocks scope.

Comment: An extra layer of indirection: write your small library that calls the functions and then have those functions exposes as extern C .

Comment: Or if it's a relatively big project which requires a lot of P/Invokes, use C++/CLI, which is specifically designed for this purpose. You can then directly add a reference to your mixed binary.

Comment: Your code very specifically does **not** concern C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I thought it does at bit because I want C-linkage.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts I thought about this as well, it seemed the .def file would be less work, that's why I didn't do it (yet). Another thing that kind of bothers me with this approach is that (as far as I know) to rename all the functions to avoid duplicate declaration errors. Or is there a way to preven those?

Comment: @Neijwiert Thank you, that sounds pretty useful. I never worked with C++/CLI though and the language looks a little confusing. Since the project deadline is pretty close I'm not sure if there's enough time to learn it. I'll definitely keep this option in mind though!

Comment: @katzenversteher the C/C++ linkage is a C++ thing. If you've got a function with non-C-linkage the only solutions are those that do involve C++ and not C at all.

Comment: @katzenversteher unfortunately if you want a c interface I don't see any other way. But maybe you can automate the process with some scripting

Comment: This just isn't a real problem, you've got the [DllImport]'s EntryPoint property to declare the mangled name.  In fact it is highly desirable, if the library owner ever changes the definition of a function then you get a nice runtime error instead of a very ugly stack corruption problem.  But you have to get the .def file correct and you left no breadcrumbs to guess why that is a problem.  Use the linker's .map file to see the mangled name.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the hint with the .map file. I didn't think of it and activated creation of the map file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++ one way (IMHO the most elegant) would be using C++/CLI, which is designed for that. Especially if you have not only functions but also classes.

You create a thin wrapper layer which is fairly simple:

1. Create a CLI class
2. put a member instance of the original class
3. wrap all public methods from the original class

Like This (untested):

**C++ nativ:**

```
// original c++ class
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int v) : m_value(v) {}
    ~Foo() {}

    int  value()      { return m_value; }
    void value(int v) { m_value = v; }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

**CLI wrapper:**

```
// C++/CLI wrapper
ref class FooWrap
{
public:
    FooWrap(int v) { m_instance = new Foo(v); }
    !FooWrap()     { delete m_instance; }
    ~FooWrap()     { this->!FooWrap(); }

    property int value {
        int  get()      { return m_instance->value(); }
        void set(int v) { m_instance->value(v); }
    }

private:
    Foo *m_instance;
};
```

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8) you can find a short howto, which describes it in more detail.

### Edit:

From your comments:

> [...] I never worked with C++/CLI though and the language looks a little confusing. Since the project deadline is pretty close I'm not sure if there's enough time to learn it. I'll definitely keep this option in mind though!

If you are **not** looking for the most elegant way, as in your original question, but for the fastest/shortest way: For C++ one way (IMHO the shortest way) would be using C++/CLI, which is designed for that. Especially if you have not only functions but also classes. You create a thin wrapper layer which is fairly simple... [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8) you can find a short (in 10 min) howto, which describes it in more detail.

Comment: Your `FooWrap` class should implement `IDisposable`. Also `~FooWrap` is implicitly the `Dispose` method. Since you're handling unmanaged handles you should use the finalizer, which is `!FooWrap`.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example! Just for clarification (I also added it to my original question): I only want to expose functions, there is (as far I can tell) no cpp functionality involved and I don't understand why the original author of the library did not put these functions inside of the `extern "C"` block as well...

Comment: @katzenversteher there are some [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46116950/1810087) with extern "C". Putting every function into extern "C" is not convenient for C++ functions. I could imagine the original author only extern "C" 'd functions he needed for his own work?!