# Automatically modifying C library to be used by C++

Tags: c++, c

I'd like to make a tool that automatically wraps `C` libraries in:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

But I'm confused by *what* exactly needs to be wrapped with `extern "C"`, and what needn't be. Only functions? What about any (*shock-horror*) global variables? Anything else?

If I write a script that just finds all functions and wraps them with `extern "C"`, is that enough?

And finally: if the library already wrapped its functions with `extern "C"` and then they're wrapped again, can I trust that nothing bad happens and it'll still work fine, or do I need to explicitly check for this?

Comment: `extern "C"` may not be the only thing you have to worry about. A few constructs are valid in C, but invalid in C++ (e.g. anonymous structs). The C library header files need to be free of such constructs. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter, because anything that does not need it (such as macros and comments) will be unaffected by it, so you can just wrap the entire header content - and that hardly requires a a "tool".

Also not this is not "modifying the library", just modifying the header.

Nested wrapping is benign - applying C linkage to something that already has it has no effect.

What `extern "C"` does is tell the *C++* compiler not to apply name mangling to the specified symbol because it has C linkage and the corresponding name in the library has C linkage and *is not* name-mangled.

Name-mangling is the means by which C++ applies meta-data to a symbols in order to provide type information and parameter counts in order to support C++ features that require this information such as function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292138/when-to-use-extern-c-in-c) which is partially related.

You'll basically just want to either:

1. Autowrap an include, i.e. `extern "C" { #include <foo.h> }`
2. Autowrap the C header files being included by the include (so, at the start of "foo.h" as opposed to the include statement itself)

As far as doubly-wrapped `extern "C"`s, I tested it with these files:

lib.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void printHWorld(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

lib.c:

```
#include <stdlio.h>
#include <lib.h>

void printHWorld(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    #include <lib.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main(void) {
    printHWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

I then built it with the following commands:

`gcc  -Wall -O2 -I. -o lib.o -c lib.c`

`g++  -Wall -O2 -I. -o main.o -c main.cpp`

`g++ -o test main.o lib.o`

And that worked just fine, so I don't think you need to worry about the double `extern "C"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm having difficulty understanding the first part of your answer. I just wrap the C filename at the include point in C++ code? So I don't need to modify the C library? And I don't need to wrap functions? Please could you explain more clearly - thanks!

Comment: @Alasdair According to one of the answers on the other question I linked to, you can just do: `extern "C" { #include "library_file.h" }`